# How to keep program running on VPS even after it's closed?

Tags: vps, remote-server

I want to apologize for the question I'm going to ask if it's not clear and detailed enough.
I delivered a program (`developed using VB.Net`) to an online client, it's an automation program that simulates user keystrokes (using `SendKeys`) on a windows OS.
All went well, but he said that when he runs the program on `VPS`, program closes when he closes VPS, although other programs keep running.

I hope someone here can help me with explaining to me the reason behind this issue, and if there's any fix for it. The problem is that I don't have access to the client's VPS since he's an online client.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
I got access to client's VPS, program throw an exception when connection to VPS is closed, exception message: `System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs`

Comment: What is the operating system of the VPS, and how is the program executed?

Comment: So far I know it's windows, I sent him an email asking him which OS specifically he's using.
User clicks a button, and the program run an application and starts sending keystorkes to this aplication.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the remote desktop connection to the Windows VPS. When the user logs off the remote connection the .EXE / Application is halted and will no longer run. To work around this you can do one of the following:

1. Create a new Windows Service Project from the New Project button in the Visual Studio, and then just program your application as a service. [Linked Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. Use the Service management Window within the VPS environment and add the executable file of your program. It will start running as a service, (with visible windows and everything as you coded it) and will run when the user logs out. [Linked Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685150(v=vs.85).aspx)
3. Use the Task Manager to schedule a task that will run the executable file on certain conditions (like system startup). [Linked Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7)

If it is something run by multiple clients I would use option 1 as it provides portability and easy of deployment. It will most likely require a refactor in someway or another though.

If it is a single use application and will not be used by anyone else, but is going to be a constant presence on the VPS then I would use option 2.

I would only use option 3 if you need further control over the conditions in which the script runs.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you a lot Matt, many thanks :)
Option 2 is what you recommend in my case, but I'm trying option 1 out of curiosity.

Comment: But can you please give me instruction how to apply option 2?
I checked the link you listed above, but I couldn't find how to add my exe as a service!

Comment: You can option the command prompt (ctrl r) and enter `services.msc` and that will start it. You should then have an option to add a service and select your .EXE from the directory it is stored in.

Comment: This is what I did, I went to services and tried to see a menu item to add new service, I tried to right click on services (Local) but still couldn't find this option to add a service!

Comment: Option nb 1 didn't work either.
I created a windows server project, and it ran correctly on the VPS, but still when connection to VPS is closed, program threw an exception and quit.
I hope option 2 works, but still didn't find the add service option.

Comment: I forgot to list the exception thrown: "System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs"